# Entity Framework 4 inheritance issue when deployed

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, entity-framework-4

I have an ASP.NET page using EF 4,

It has a couple of tables linked using an inheritance relationship. Locally when running on the ASP.NET Development Server it all works fine, when I deploy to IIS however (Windows server 2003) I'm getting the error:

```
The ResultType of the specified expression is not compatible with the required type. 
The expression ResultType is 'Transient.reference[A]' but the required type 
is 'Transient.reference[B]'
```

where A : B

I have found https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/544639/ef4-inheritance-defined-using-queryview-doesnt-work-properly-with-association

But that doesn't explain why it works on the development server (though I do have .net 4.5 installed, but the development server says it's running on 4.0) and why only this class/table has this problem.

I have other tables which have the same kind of relationships and the code for those works fine.

I can't paste the code, but in EF I'm doing something like:

`var Bs = Repository.A.OfType<B>().Include(..).ToList();`